# LOGIC - Completeness vs Consistent

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

One of my exams questions were the following (translated from Hebrew)

Course is in Artificial Intelligence, and is about Logic in this question.

> What is a consistent logic system?
>   What is a complete logic system?
>   **If you had the chance to chose a consistent system or a complete system which would you chose and why?**

The question in bold is the one i need an answer to, but feel free to define what a consistent / complete system is before answering the question.

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: By "complete system" do we mean "complete and consistent"? I'd always prefer a consistent system over an inconsistent one ;/

Comment: the question does not say if the complete system is consistent, otherwise it would be easy to answer it, it just compares consistent and complete.

Comment: An inconsistent logic system $S$ is kind of appealing. Under the usual rules of logic, any sentence $\varphi$ is then a theorem of $S$. So I could prove many theorems (some true, some false) quickly. (And let this not be taken seriously.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas You made me laugh :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas lol :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how general the term "logic system" is supposed to be, so I'll assume it means a theory — a set of sentences of first order logic, in some particular language (set of constants, predicates, function symbols).

A theory $T$ is *inconsistent* iff it for some sentence $S$ in its language it proves both $T\vdash S$ and $T\vdash \neg S$. An inconsistent theory proves *every sentence*. A theory is *consistent* iff it's not inconsistent.

A theory $T$ is *complete* iff it's a maximal consistent set of sentences: the theory is consistent, and for every sentence $S$ of its language, $T$ proves either $S$ or $\neg S$: $T\vdash$ or $T\vdash \neg S$ (but, by consistency, not both).

Note on usage: sometimes *complete* may be defined without the requirement of consistency. According to that definition, a theory $T$ is *complete'* (let's designate it) iff for every sentence $S$ of its language, $T$ proves either $S$ or $\neg S$: $T\vdash$ or $T\vdash \neg S$ (or, possibly, both! — every inconsistent system is *complete'*). Since this is an exam question, obviously your course has introduced one definition or the other: you'd know which one, and there's no sense in my guessing. If your working definition is the weaker one, then I would always prefer a consistent theory to an inconsistent one, although the latter is *complete'*.

I would always prefer a complete consistent theory that extends a merely consistent theory, *provided* the theories are "recursively axiomatizable", in the sense that it's decidable which sentences are in the theory and which aren't. In that case, the complete theory has a decision procedure, its set of theorems is nontrivial and recursive (decidable), whereas the theorems of a recursively axiomatizable consistent theory are merely recursively enumerable (r.e., semi-decidable).

Note that in the previous paragraph, the requirement of "recursively axiomatizability" is important. Theories are abstract things, arbitrary sets of sentences. If $T$ is the theory consisting of all sentences of arithmetic that are true in the standard model of the integers, then $T$ is complete, but is highly non-decidable (much, much more complex than, for example, the halting problem). In this case, I'd prefer the theory PA (Peano arithmetic): $T$ extends PA, but at least PA is semi-decidable.

Comment: In the terminology I'm familiar with, complete doesn't imply consistent, in fact every inconsistent system is complete.  This way we can state Gödel's theorem as "it cannot be both consistent and complete".  Your answer is great, but do you have a reference for those definitions?

Comment: @DanBrumleve It seems usage may vary. Here's a reference: [Complete theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory) I added a paragraph to address this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and the professor didn't mention the actual definition of completeness (in the slides at least, i wasnt in the lesson), but i get what you are saying as in - if complete implies consistent then obvious we want complete, but if complete doesnt necessary imply consistent then we would want a consistent theory.

Comment: Ya, exactly... *other things being equal*, namely, assuming we can tell which sentences are **in** the theory in the first place! (recursively axiomatizable). Since it's an AI class, recursively axiomatizability is probably a given: you can't very well compute on a theory that isn't :) But it's important to be clear about that.